# Why I can't print my stored Date in Core Data ? Swift

Tags: swift, date, core-data, fetch

I'm stuck in my app development with a stupid issue for hours... 
Could someone help me fix this issue please ?

I have no issue for print all my data except the "game_releasedate" data that is a "Date" data

```
    let foundgame = GameClass()

    //Look into Database

    let request = NSFetchRequest<NSFetchRequestResult>(entityName: "Game_BDD")
    request.predicate = NSPredicate(format: "game_barcode == %@", barcode)
    print (barcode)


    //Autofill the game name, console, region, etc...
    do {
        let result = try context.fetch(request)
        print (result.count)
        if result.count > 0 {
            foundgame.game_Name = (result[0] as AnyObject).value(forKey: "game_name") as! String
            foundgame.game_Console = (result[0] as AnyObject).value(forKey: "game_console") as! String
            foundgame.game_Genre = (result[0] as AnyObject).value(forKey: "game_genre") as! String
            foundgame.game_Publisher = (result[0] as AnyObject).value(forKey: "game_publisher") as! String
            foundgame.game_Region = (result[0] as AnyObject).value(forKey: "game_country") as! String
            let date = (result[0] as AnyObject).value(forKey: "game_releasedate") as! NSDate

            print(date)

         }
        else
        {
            foundgame.game_Name = "Barcode Not found"
        }

    }
    catch{
        print("Error looking in the DB")
    }
```

Thank you

Edit :

This is how i put my game data into the database :

```
        let formatdate = DateFormatter()
        formatdate.dateFormat = "dd/mm/yyyy"
        print(gametxt[3])


        let newGame = NSEntityDescription.insertNewObject(forEntityName: "Game_BDD", into: context) as NSManagedObject
        newGame.setValue(gametxt[0], forKey: "game_console")
        newGame.setValue(gametxt[1], forKey: "game_genre")
        newGame.setValue(gametxt[2], forKey: "game_name")
        newGame.setValue(gametxt[3], forKey: "game_country")
        newGame.setValue(gametxt[4], forKey: "game_publisher")
        newGame.setValue(gametxt[5], forKey: "game_productid")
        newGame.setValue(gametxt[6], forKey: "game_barcode")
        newGame.setValue(formatdate.date(from: gametxt[7]), forKey: "game_releasedate")
```

Comment: and what is the issue?

Comment: there is 'nil' in date

Comment: Could you print fetched result? Does it contain date value?

Comment: Thank you so much for your help, this is the error message I have :

fatal error: unexpectedly found nil while unwrapping an Optional value
2017-09-17 15:59:38.476889+0200 GameCollection[10080:3482019] fatal error: unexpectedly found nil while unwrapping an Optional value
(lldb)

Comment: The error says that there's no value for that property.

Comment: For sure i have something store in the database in this table and with this key T_T but maybe it wasn't store properly ? I didn't have any error when I saved it on the database

Comment: I have edited my post with the code I use to store the date. I should have missed something. Thank you so much everyone

Comment: Most likely the date does not match `dd/mm/yyyy` which is no surprise because `mm` is minute rather than month.

Comment: Thank you ! Now i'm wandering how I should save a date in the CoreData database...

Comment: The date conversion in swift is just a nightmare... For example how do I convert "04/14/97" into a valid NSDate ?

Answer (score 1):

For changing date to the valid date:

**// if your date is in `Date` format**

```
let date = Date()
let dateFormatter = DateFormatter()
dateFormatter.dateFormat = "dd/MM/yyyy"

print(dateFormatter.string(from: date)) // outputs : 17/09/2017
```

**// if your date is in `String` format**

```
let dateString = "04/14/97"
let dateFormatter = DateFormatter()
dateFormatter.dateFormat = "mm/dd/yy"
let date = dateFormatter.date(from: dateString)
dateFormatter.dateFormat = "dd/mm/yyyy"

print(dateFormatter.string(from: date!)) // outputs : 14/04/1997
```